# Request Topic search should include Topics pending approval

Tags: feature-request, documentation

When you click on `Request Topic` and do a search, it should also search in the topics that haven't been approved yet.

I just created a topic on padding in CSS, only to find out after that there is another one awaiting approval.

*Incidentally the topic that was a dupe to mine has now been retracted - not sure if the OP saw this post or not. It still is a potential issue though.*